# CSS file works offline but not when uploaded to webserver

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just completed my portfolio website and uploaded it to a subdomain of my parent website.

Now the website works fine except that my main styling CSS doesn't work, no errors in the console, nothing. It just doesn't work. I verified it by placing the CSS in `<style>` tags in the head of my index.html and it worked but then it messed up with my paroller.js plugin, no errors in the console but paroller.js stopped working.

If I include the CSS like I've included it offline (in a separate file, like I always do and it always works on the same web server) it just doens't work. If I include it in the index.html my paroller.js plugin stops working.

Everything works fine offline.

I'm importing the CSS like this - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="folername/filename.css">`
Please note that I am loading multiple CSSs and this one is the first to be loaded. All other CSSs seem to be working.

The webpage is located at - https://yadullah.piware.tech

Comment: just a sugesstion :P try to fix the horizontal scroll that is coming due to the portfolio section

Comment: Could you please make sure that css file is uploaded to server ?

Comment: What is css file name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed something strange... I accessed the main CSS and JS files using `yadullah.piware.tech/foldername/filename` and noticed that the files weren't updated. I refreshed the page a couple of times and they updated themselves.

The webpage is working perfectly now.

I believe this has happened due to the server taking time to update/replace the updated files. Still, if anyone has got any better explanation for this please let me know.

Comment: your browser is serving you CSS from the cache that's why they are not updated. if you are on chrome open the developers tools and hold the reload button when the menu pop up choose empty cache and reload

Comment: @radtelbi Ctrl+F5 should have the same effect in Chrome